Не работает поворот камеры свайпами
Есть два скрипта, в одном с помощью интерфейса IBeginDragHundler, считываются свайпы и вектор поворота приравнивается к evenData.delta.
public class CameraControl : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IBeginDragHandler
{
    [HideInInspector] public static Vector2 napravlenie;
    [SerializeField] private float sensivity = 6;
    public static bool Moved = false;
    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData) 
    {
        Moved = true;
        napravlenie = eventData.delta * sensivity * Time.deltaTime; ;
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData) { }
} 

И второй скрипт, отвечающий непосредственно за поворот камеры.
[SerializeField] private Transform Camera;
private float AnglRot;
private void Update()
{
    if (CameraControl.Moved == true) { Rotation(); }
}
public void Rotation()
{
    AnglRot = Mathf.Clamp(AnglRot - CameraControl.napravlenie.y, -90, 90);
    Camera.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(AnglRot, 0, 0);
    transform.Rotate(transform.up, CameraControl.napravlenie.x);
}

Но в итогу поворот не работает, какие могут быть ошибки и как их исправить?
